# Chrome Extension получить id или url активной вкладки

Tags: chrome-extension, tab

Всегда получаю `undefined`, пробовал разными популярными способами, например:

```
var tabId = chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
   return tabs[0].id;
});
```

Необходимо при клике на ссылку из popup открыть другую страницу и в ней получить url или tabId(что бы получить url) активной вкладки.

Права приложения стоят activeTab, tabs

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `chrome.tabs.query` является асинхронным. Это значит что вы не можете вернуть из него значение через return (синхронно).

Пример рабочего варианта:

```
var tabId; 
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
   tabId = tabs[0].id;
   myAction(); // код, который зависит от tabId
});

function myAction() {
    // тут уже можно работать с полученным tabId
}
```

Также, можно передать tabId в `myAction` в качестве аргумента, что будет корректнее.

Рекомендую ознакомиться с вопросом: "[Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290)"

Comment: Спасибо,но  уже и сам понял что не правильно работаю с api